# Why is escaping double quotes in mySQL not returning a result?

Tags: mysql, sql, escaping

I have a basic table (user) with a 'username' column and a 'userid' column
For now I have 2 entries:

```
USER                USER ID
---------------------------
Mark                0
A's Catcher         1
B"s Catcher         2
```

I have tried 3 queries, and the query with double quotes fails for some reason, as follows:

1) **WORKS**: If I do the following query

```
select * from user where username = 'Mark';
```

2) **WORKS**:  If I do the following query

```
select * from user where username = 'A\'s Catcher';
```

3) **DOES NOT WORK**: If I do this query it gives me 0 results..

```
select * from user where username = 'B\"s Catcher';
```

I'm totally confused, I feel like i've escaped double quotes like this before without any problems..  What am I missing here?

Comment: Why would you need to escape the double quote? It won't cause any conflict with the surrounding single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is like PHP aware of the first quote type:

```
 '"' // a String with a "
 "'" // a String with a '
```

only the outer quotes need to be escape in the inside:

```
 '\'' // a string with a '
 "\"" // a string with a "
```

Thus

```
 'B\"s Catcher' // is a string literally containing: B\"s Catcher
```

sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb8d3c/1

Comment: Makes total sense!  Thanks!    So if I am stuck with strings always escaped as A\'s Catcher and B\"s Catcher is there anyway of forming an SQL string or am I up the creek?

Comment: You may use prepared statements (what language is that), this will prevent the escaping nightmare ...

Comment: Im working in a PHP framework that escapes all strings (to prevent SQL injection) so its always giving me escaped single and double quotes no matter what.  I could manually unescape the double quotes I guess, but it seems like a bad idea for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE username = CONCAT('B','"','s Catcher');
```